# How do I get list of 'personal account' users who have logged into my WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am building a webapp which has a login page that does the authentication through openID, using passport.js library.

On the Azure AD I have registered an app as multi-tenant, that successfully allows personal accounts to log in.

This is what I could achieve till now.

What I want to know is, a way to keep track of these users who have been authenticated so far on the app.
i.e. get a list of mail ids, and their names.

Is there any API to know who all have consented?